# Create continuous matrix of rectangles from set of rectangles

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, matrix, rectangles

I have a set of objects(each object contains a rectangle and a value assigned to it) which is kept in a vector container.
See picture below:
[image]

I need to create a matrix by drawing horizontal and vertical lines at each y/x lower left (LL) / upper right(UR) coordinate like below:
[image]

And I need to assign value = 0 to each new empty rectangle, and to other rectangles which are inside of initial rectangles, I need to assign their old values.
I've implemented this with some naive algorithm but it works too slow when I have huge number of rectangles. My algorithm basically does the following: 
- Stores all rectangles in a map container. Each element of the map contains set of rectangles with the same LL Y coordinate and they are sorted by LL X coordinate, i.e. key is LL Y coordinate.
- Stores all X/Y coordinates in set containers.
- Iterates over Y/X coordinate containers, and for each new rectangle finds out if it exists in map or not, if exists-assigns existing value to it, otherwise-assigns 0 value. I.e, for each new rectangle it looks for its LL Y coordinate in map, if such Y exists, then searches through the corresponding value(set of rectangles), otherwise-it searches in a whole map.

Is there an effective algorithm to get needed results?

Comment: you should show your code and then the question is probably better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Ok, but I think this is very simple/slow algorithm, and need to come up with a different smarter algorithm.

Comment: we cannot know how to make your implementation more efficient if you dont show us your implementation. I personally would find it easier to understand your algorithm by looking at code rather than your explanation in text

Comment: Ok, I'll my code later today.

Comment: why does the resultant matrix in your example extend below the lowest rectangle?

Comment: Thanks for the catch, actually it's a mistake :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For n rectangles this can be solved easily in **O(n^3) time** (or just O(n^2) time if at most a bounded number of rectangles intersect) by looking at the problem a different way.  This should be adequate for handling up to thousands of rectangles in a few seconds.

Also, unless some other constraints are added to the problem, the latter time bound is optimal: that is, there exist inputs consisting of n non-intersecting rectangles for which O(n^2) smaller grid rectangles will need to be output (which of course requires O(n^2) time).  An example such input is n width-1 rectangles, all having equal bottommost y co-ord and having heights 1, 2, ..., n.

## Grid size bounds

First of all, notice that there can be at most 2n vertical lines, and at most 2n horizontal lines, since each input rectangle introduces at most 2 of each kind (it may introduce less if one or both vertical lines are also the edge(s) for some already-considered rectangle, and likewise for horizontal lines).  So there can be at most (2*n - 1)^2 = O(n^2) cells in the grid defined by these lines.

## The grid cell co-ordinate system

We can invent a co-ordinate system for grid cells in which each cell is identified by its lower-left corner, and the co-ordinates of an intersection of two grid lines is given simply by the number of horizontal grid lines below it and the number of vertical grid lines to its left (so that the bottommost, leftmost grid cell has co-ords (0, 0), the cell to its right has co-ords (1, 0), the cell two cells above *that* cell has co-ords (1, 2), etc.)

## The algorithm

For each input rectangle having LL co-ords (x1, y1) and UR co-ords (x2, y2), we determine the horizontal and vertical intervals that it occupies within the new grid co-ordinate system, and then simply iterate through every cell (i, j) belonging to this rectangular region (i.e., every grid cell (i, j) such that toGridX(x1) <= i < toGridX(x2) and toGridY(y1) <= j < toGridY(y2)) with a nested `for` loop, recording in a hashtable that the ID (colour?) for the cell at (i, j) should be the colour of the current input rectangle.  Input rectangles should be processed in decreasing z-order (implicitly at least there seems to be such an order, from your example) so that for any cell covered by more than one input rectangle, the hashtable will wind up recording whatever the "nearest" rectangle's colour is.  Finally, iterate through the hash table, converting each grid co-ord pair (i, j) back to the LL and UR co-ords of the input-space rectangle that corresponds to this grid cell, and output this rectangle with the ID given by the value for this hash key.

## Preprocessing

In order to accomplish the above, we need two things: a way to map input-space co-ordinates to grid co-ordinates (to determine the horizontal and vertical grid intervals for a given input rectangle), and a way to map grid co-ordinates back to input-space co-ordinates (to generate the output rectangles in the final step).  Both operations are easy to do via that old workhorse, *sorting*.

Given any corner (x, y) of some input rectangle, **the grid x co-ordinate corresponding to x, toGridX(x), is simply the *rank position* of x within the sorted list of all *distinct* x positions of vertical edges that are present among the input rectangles.**  Similarly, toGridY(y) is just the rank position of y within the sorted list of all distinct y positions of horizontal edges that are present among the input rectangles.  In the other direction, for any grid co-ordinate (i, j), the corresponding input-space x co-ordinate, fromGridX(i), is simply the i-th smallest x co-ord (ignoring duplicates) of any vertical edge among the input rectangles, and similarly for fromGridY(j).  These can all be computed as follows (all array indices start at 0, and I show only how to do it for x co-ords; y co-ords are similar):

1. For each rectangle i in the input having LL co-ords (x1, y1) and (x2, y2):

   - Append the two-element array [x1, i] to the list-of-arrays VERT.
   - Append the two-element array [x2, i] to the list-of-arrays VERT.
2. Sort the list VERT in increasing order by its first item.
3. Combine elements in VERT having identical x co-ords.  Specifically:

   1. Set j = 0.
   2. For i from 1 to n-1:

      - If VERT[i][0] == VERT[j][0] then append VERT[i][1] to VERT[j] (thereby forming an array of length 3 or more at position j), otherwise set j = j + 1 and overwrite VERT[j] with the two-element array VERT[i].
   3. Delete VERT[j+1] and all later elements from VERT.
4. By this time, for any i, VERT[i] is an array that contains (in its second and subsequent positions) the IDs of every input rectangle that uses, as either its left or right edge, the ith-leftmost distinct vertical line used by any input rectangle -- or in other words, the rank-i vertical line.  We now "invert" this:

   - For i from 0 to n-1:

     - For j from 1 to length(VERT[i])-1:

       - Set toGridX[VERT[i][j]] = i.
5. For i from 0 to length(VERT)-1:

   - Set fromGridX[i] = VERT[i][0].

## Running time

As previously established, there are at most O(n^2) grid cells.  Each of the n input rectangles can occupy at most all of these cells, each of which is visited once per input rectangle, for a time bound of O(n^3).  Note that this is an extremely pessimistic time bound, and for example if none (or none but a bounded number) of your rectangles overlap, then it drops to O(n^2) since no grid cell will ever be visited more than once.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, in my test case there are about 2 million rectangles, so, seems this run time will take quite long.

Comment: As I said in my answer, the O(n^2) time bound is optimal -- that is, *any* algorithm will take at least this long on these "nasty" inputs, since at least that many rectangles would need to be output, and you can't output a rectangle in less than O(1) time.

Comment: Ok, I see. I'll try it out then.

Comment: In practice, it should be very fast -- besides actually writing out the output squares, the only thing that takes any time is the two sorting steps.  And even for 4 million entries, that won't take long :)

Comment: I'm getting about 10 min run-time on my machine which is quite good. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Would you suggest to use the same algorithm to check if overlapping rectangles found?

Comment: I would, yes.  You can easily check for overlapping rectangles by testing whether the grid cell you are about to set the colour for already has an entry in the hashtable.

Comment: I was wondering if there is more effective algorithm for overlaps check :)

Comment: If all you want to do is determine at least one pair of overlapping rectangles (or prove that no pair overlaps), you could do a simpler all-pairs test in O(n^2) time.  You could speed this up in practice (though not in the worst case, due to the possibility of "nasty" instances) by first sorting all rectangles by e.g. their rightmost x co-ord: then to check for overlaps with the ith rectangle, you need only walk j backwards from i-1, stopping as soon as either you get an overlap, or you meet a rectangle whose rightmost x co-ord is <= the ith rectangle's leftmost x co-ord.

Comment: Ok, seems algorithm suggested in your answer is working quite fast, I'm processing my rectangles gradually, so the intersections can be found in early stage (because otherwise processing all rectangles was taking too long).

Comment: Glad to hear it :)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the lookups and iterations are not fast enough. Things like 'otherwise it searches the whole map' point out that you do very heavy computations.

What I think you need is to use a 2d datastructure. A k-d tree or a BSP would work but the easiest to understand and implement would be a quad tree.

In a quad tree each node represents a rectangle in your space. Each node can be split into 4 children by selecting the mid point along the 2 dimensions and having the children represent the 4 resulting rectangles. Each node also holds the value that you want to assign to the area and an extra flag if the value is uniform.

To mark a rectangle with some value, you start from the root and recursively:

- If the input rectangle covers the node rectangle you set the value to that node, mark it as uniform and return.
- If the input rectangle and the node rectangle don't touch just return.
- If the node is marked as uniform, copy the value to it's children and mark the node not uniform.
- Recursively call for the 4 children (you might have to create them).
- On the way back, check if the 4 children have the same value and are all marked as uniform and if so mark the node as uniform and set the same value as the children.

The main advantage of this approach is that you get to mark large areas of your map quickly. You can also prove that marking a area is O(logN) where N is the size of your map (with a larger constant than the usual tree).

You can find a more detailed explanation and some helpful images on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know the top- and bottom-most `y` and the left- and right-most `x`, extend the four vectors belonging to each rectangle to the respective max and min `x` and `y` points. Keep a set of extended vertical vectors and a set of extended horizontal ones. Whenever an extended vector is added, it will necessarily intersect with each vector in the perpendicular list - the intersections are the cell coordinates of the matrix.

Once the list of cell coordinates is made, iterate over them and assign values appropriately, looking up if they are in or out of an original rectangle. I'm not too versed in data structures for rectangles, but it seems to me that two interval trees, one for horizontal, the other for vertical could find that answer in `O(log n)` time per query, where `n` is the number of intervals in the tree.

All together, this method seems to be `O(n * log m)` time, where `n` is the number of cell coordinates in the resultant matrix and `m` is the number of original rectangles.